# Why Google Earth insert a LookAt attribute in my KML files? How to remove it?

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-pro

When I build a KMZ file in Google Earth Pro, when I reopen it, the initial view is in a place that I can't understand where it comes from, far away from the KMZ location and it's always the same place also for other KMZ file that I create.
I expect to open the initial view over on KMZ file extents, but it always bring me to a specific position that I can't find on Google Earth preferences.

If I look into the KMZ file opening it with a textviewer, I find the  attribute.

The problem is that I cannot understand where it comes from, because I've not inserted any specific point inside the KMZ file when I created it.

Any idea?

Comment: KML tilt and range equals the LookAt https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/cameras use the example and modify

Comment: My question is: I can't understand why and from where my Kmz inherited the LookAt element

Answer (score 1):

When you save an thing to KMZ, the KMZ file will contain the perspective associated with the thing.  For example, a Placemark you've created using the toolbar.  Try double-clicking on that thing you want to save in the sidebar and see if GE navigates to that same weird perspective that you got with the KMZ.

If this is the case, then you can modify that thing (e.g., Placemark) by right clicking on it, selecting Properties, working with the View tab.  Perhaps also while you're in there see if the View tab settings are the same as those you saw in the KML in your text editor.

Comment: If I double click an element of the KMZ file, the view moves to the correct position. The problem is when I open the KMZ file: there is a LookUp element that brings me to a specific point on the map that has nothing to do with the KMZ. It's always the same point for every KMZ file I open. I've found it in KMZ file. It is saved in it when I create the KMZ, but I don't put nothing at that point! It seems like a default view inside GE saved into the KMZ file, but I cannot find it in preferences.

Comment: Could it be that this mysterious point is the center point between all the elements in your KMZ?  You say there's nothing there, but perhaps if you were saving a number of elements when you created the KMZ, GE designated a LookAt that would center the viewer on your group of elements.  Try saving a single element to KMZ and see if you get the same problematic behavior.

Comment: No, it isn't the in middle of the  elements. It is always the same point also for kmz elements in different places